# Trying to make a alert program HELP UPDATING JLIST

Tags: java, swing, alert, jlist

***Hello***, i am trying to make a program that alerts you when an upcoming event is close or a project is due.  I am having some trouble with the JList.  When I try and remove a event/project it doesn't refresh i have already tried `list.updateUI()` and making list invisible then making it visible again to try and refresh it but nothing has worked if you can help ***thank you in advance***
Here is the java code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import javax.swing.*;

public class alarm implements ActionListener {
public static JFrame window;
public static JPanel p;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static JList list;
public RandomAccessFile rw;
public int[] numberArray;
public String[] name;
public String[] desc;
public String[] date;
public JButton remove;
String[] listData = new String[1000000];
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void windowList() {
    list = new JList(name);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
    pane.setBounds(100, 10, 400, 400);
    p.add(pane);
    pane.setVisible(true);
}
public void dataLoad() throws IOException {
    try {
        rw = new RandomAccessFile("db.txt", "rw");
        int loop = 0;
        int insertNumber = 0;
        numberArray = new int[1000000];
        name = new String[1000000];
        desc = new String[1000000];
        date = new String[1000000];
        String row = "";
        while(loop == 0) {
             row = rw.readLine();
            if(rw.getFilePointer() == rw.length()) {
                insertNumber = 0;
                loop = 1;
            }else if(row.equals("/")) {
                insertNumber = insertNumber + 1;
                numberArray[insertNumber] = insertNumber;
                name[insertNumber] = rw.readLine();
                desc[insertNumber] = rw.readLine();
                date[insertNumber] = rw.readLine();
            }
        }
        while(loop == 1) {
            insertNumber = insertNumber + 1;
            if(name[insertNumber] == null) {
                loop = 2;
            }else {
                System.out.println(name[insertNumber]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Arrays Loaded");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void dataRemove() throws IOException {
    rw = new RandomAccessFile("db.txt", "rw");
    int remove = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int countR = 0;
    String tempData = "";
    String value = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
    rw.seek(0);
    while(remove == 0) {
        tempData = rw.readLine();
        System.out.println(tempData);
        if(rw.getFilePointer() == rw.length()) {
            System.out.println("Not found...");
            remove = 1;
        }else if(tempData.equals(value)) {
            countR = count;
            count = 0;
            remove = 1;
        }
        else if(tempData.equals("/")) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    rw.seek(0);
    System.out.println("Starting loop 2");
    while(remove == 1) {
        tempData = rw.readLine();
        if(tempData.equals("/")) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if(count == countR) {
            rw.seek(rw.getFilePointer()-2);
            rw.writeBytes("/");
            remove = 2;
        }
    }

    numberArray = new int[1000000];
    name = new String[1000000];
    desc = new String[1000000];
    date = new String[1000000];
    dataLoad();
}
alarm() throws IOException {
    dataLoad();
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setSize(600, 600);
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(null);
    window.add(p);
    remove = new JButton("Remove");
    remove.addActionListener(this);
    remove.setBounds(100, 415, 100, 30);
    p.add(remove);
    remove.setVisible(true);
    windowList();

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new alarm();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == remove) {
        try {
            dataRemove();
            list.setVisible(false);
            windowList();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Then take a look at [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) which has a nice handy `remove` method

Answer (score 3):

Where's your ListModel? You need to use a ListModel such as a `DefaultListModel<String>` to allow you to easily add and remove elements form the displayed `JList<String>`. You would pass the model into the JList either through its constructor or its `setModel(...)` method. Read the [JList tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) as it is all very explained there.

Other issues:

- You're using null layouts and setBounds. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Your code does not follow Java naming conventions, and you will want to learn and use them: [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.